# How to do the reverse of what a vuejs slot does normally according to the documentation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

After reading the [documentation on slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) I've come away not really understanding why they are useful, because it seems they function exactly opposite of what I need to do.

For those familiar with ASP.NET, what I really want is an `@section`. That is I have my main page layout defined in some component, and within that component I want to control one small section from within the child where the hierarchy of markup does not make this easy.

I want to have basically this same markup in my application as in the docs:

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
  <main>
    <slot></slot>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <slot name="footer"></slot>
  </footer>
</div>
```

The issue is that I want this to live in my higher level component, and then within the child I want to specify the content that goes in header, for example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 slot="header">Name Of This Page {{ DataFromChildContext }}</h1>
        <div id="remainder-of-child">
        <!snip...-->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The documentation is pretty clear, this goes in the PARENT:

> To provide content to named slots, we can use the slot attribute on a  element **in the parent:**

*emphasis mine*

Am I barking up the wrong tree or is there a way to make this work using native VueJS features? I want to define the content of the slots in the child and the slot space in the parent.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve exactly the same (child -> parent) and I have to admit I've been disappointed when I noticed it is actually parent -> child. I also wanted to define the structure of the page in my root component and then in child components to say "put that in that slot". Finally what is the option you decided to use ? That would help me a lot to decide on which option to go.
@Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slots offer an easier way to create reusable components. For example, a modal, where you can define the header and body, or some other ui widget like a custom button.

The design of Vue (and other FE/JS frameworks) is data driven, and the data flows from top down.

It sounds like what you're looking for, is that a action/data that originates at the bottom affects changes at the top level. The way to do this is to make the data available at the top level. There are plugins that can help with these cases, such as vuex and route. Vuex provides a globally accessible store, so one component can make a change, and another component can listen for that change, and it doesn't matter what the relationship is. Router is used to manage navigation between pages, and allows to easily define which component should be shown within a context of a template. You can create your own implementation too, using listeners and emit, a global bus, or even passing a function as a prop.

Comment: You are correct in the sense that I want data at the bottom level to show up at a higher level. I do have Vuex in my project, but it felt draconian to throw something in the store from the child just to pull it back out in a higher level component.

Comment: I've gone with the Vuex/store option and for my specific simple case it works well enough even if its not that elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're really looking for is named views, provided by [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views).

As an example:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Named Views</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">/</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/other">/other</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view class="view one"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view two" name="a"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view three" name="b"></router-view>
</div>
```

And in the router code:

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const Baz = { template: '<div>baz</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/',
      // a single route can define multiple named components
      // which will be rendered into <router-view>s with corresponding names.
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar,
        b: Baz
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/other',
      components: {
        default: Baz,
        a: Bar,
        b: Foo
      }
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

I recognize that in ASP.NET that's not how you do it (in that the page directly renders the sections, rather than the router logic), but I think it's as close as you'll get in Vue.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping the slots would work more like Aurelia's slots which are pretty much drop in replacement for aspnet @sections.

Answer (score 1):

A `slot` is not a parent-child relationship. It is a space to contain (but not control) arbitrary content. It is useful for writing presentation components, like a dialog, where you want the component to control all the dialog-y behavior, but it doesn't matter what the contents of the dialog are (and they may have behaviors of their own).

If you have a child component, you don't use a `slot`, you just write it in the template. Which is to say, you may be overthinking this (or I may not understand what you're trying to achieve).

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <header-child></header-child>
  </header>
```

Comment: The rationale of the question is: what if you want to render a child in different places of the parent? Imagine, you have a child called "page" with header and footer content. It would be really good to have "slots" called "header" and "footer" in the parent and poplulate them from the child (instead of having two different childs). I think it makes a lot of sense. I also surprised that the normal data flow goes in opposite direction.